# Calculate the average time between two dates

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, average

I need to find the result of a calculation that is nothing more than the **average time in days from creation to completion of a task**.

In this case, using a Redshift database (looker).

I have two dates (`2022/10/01` to `2022/10/21`) and I need to find the average day of execution of the creation of an object from start to finish.

Previously, I was able to calculate the totals of objects created per day, but I can't bring up the average:

```sql
SELECT created::date, count(n1pk_package_id)
FROM dbt_dw.base_package
WHERE fk_company_id = 245821 and created >= '2022-10-01' and created < '2022-10-22'
GROUP BY created::date
ORDER BY created DESC
```

I'm not able to do the opposite way of the count to bring the average of the range of days.

Answer (score 1):

Assumption:

- There is a `created` column in your table
- You want to know the 'average' of the `created` column

You could extract the number of days that each date is different from a base date, and then use that to determine the 'average date'. It would be something like this:

```sql
select
  date '2022-10-01' + interval '1 day' * int(avg(created - date '2022-10-01'))
from table
```

It subtracts a date (any date will do) from `created`, finds the average of that value against all desired rows, converts it to days and adds it back to that same date.